# How does one pass objects / children as props without breaking shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the two different render method of Parent Component, P :

### Example 1

```
render() {
  return 
  <ChildComponent propA={ { staticKey: staticValue} }/>
}
```

### Example 2

```
render() {
  return someStaticData.map( data => 
    <ChildComponent>
      <span> 
      {
       data.value.map(dataInner => 
         <span>
           { dataInner.value } 
         <span>
      )} 
     </span>
    </ChildComponent>
  )
}
```

### In ChildComponent

Child component handles `shouldComponentUpdate` as recommended by React Guide.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
}
```

In both the above expample cases `shallowCompare` of child component *always* returns true, even if the object / child I'm passing is exactly the same (because the references changed). This is causing a lot of wasted renders.

How does one pass a static object / child as props without breaking SCU?

Comment: Store the result of the render() in a variable that can be accessed via both examples. Now you can reference the same variable when calling SCU

Comment: @stackErr Will work for example 1. But in case of example 2, if the child is a two level nested loop, I cant take it outside.

Comment: @stackErr see the updated example #2?

Comment: Hmm,good question, its out of my expertise. Someone with more knowledge of reactjs/JS can shed some light on this.

Comment: I think you've answered your question really.. shallowCompare won't be sufficient in this case. You'll need to compare object values to tell whether it's new data or not. This is why things like immutablejs are highly popular for this problem.

Comment: you need to put in a bit more elbow grease than a one-liner... even `JSON.stringify(this.props)!=JSON.stringify(nextProps)` might still be faster than over-rendering, but you can do better with a custom introspection. try caching the last meaningful values in SCU to compare.

Comment: @azium yes, but the size of immutable.js is prohibitive in my current mobile project.

Comment: So it looks you need to compare values then!

Comment: it all depends, but i often compare stuff like `data.map(x=>x.name).join("") != ...` But you don't actually NEED to use sCU, and if you do more work implementing it than render()ing, it can actually hurt perf.

Comment: @azium How does on compare values of  propType `children` which can be nested very deep?

Comment: how is the size of immutable.js prohibitive but React is not? (React is way bigger)

Comment: @dandavis Uh.. We're building an isomporphic app on react.. So obviously we can't do without that. Whereas immutable.js has a high cost we can avoid. From the user's standpoint, the lesser the js, the better.

Comment: @dandavis btw, the rendering we are avoiding here is just VDOM render right? Diffing should mean the actual DOM is never updated?

Comment: if there are no changes to the output, the DOM will not be touched. so, if it's cheap to render(), then move on to polishing up UX instead of optimization. -my $0.02. i agreee that cutting script bloat is important, but immutable will let you instantly compare two deep objects, which is exactly what you want...

Comment: @dandavis is correct, calling render does not necessarily mean there will be dom updates, as such it's likely you won't be getting a performance hit in your examples. You can compare children though using Children helpers like http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.toarray

Answer (score 0):

Maybe switching to an immutable data structure would help since then the SCU hook will only need to compare reference inequalities:

http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable